# How do I calculate distance between two geospatial in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to locate all the places near a point (GeoJson). I can easily use `near` method on the Model to find them.

But, I also need the distances from the current location to be stored in the final output as a virtual property.

I believe I should use geoNear command somewhere but I am a complete noob to MongoDB or mongoose(I'm using v4) and do not know what commands are or how to use them (particularly in mongoose).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [aggregate near](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-near). Example:

```js
mongoose.model('ModelName').aggregate().near({
  near: [lng, lat],
  distanceField: 'distance'
})
```